# React router, link to a new webpage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

basically, I am trying to redo my website and in that process, I am trying to automate as much as possible, so that if I ever need to add information I just need to change one file.

The dilema I am facing is the following, in my App.js I have written the following code:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <div className="Header">
          <Header />
          <div className="content">
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/">
                <Home />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/about">
                <About />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/work">
                <Work />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/contact">
                <Contact />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/redo">
                <KTH />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/kth">
                <KTH />
              </Route>
              <Route path="/codecademy">
                <Codecademy />
              </Route>
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </div>
      </Router>

      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem I am facing is that in a component named "Work" I want it to link to my websites I have created sometimes and to other components in other situations. The function responsible for this looks as follows:

```
function itemContent() {
  const workedItems = Object.values(worked);

  return (
    <div>
    {workedItems.map(item =>
      <div className="item">
          <div className="itemPic">
            <Link to={item.path}><img src={item.picture} alt={item.alt} /></Link>
          </div>
          <div className="itemInfo">
            <div className="itemInfoLeft">
              <p>{item.title}</p>
              <p>{item.intro}</p>
            </div>
            <div className="itemInfoRight">
              <p>{item.source}</p>
              <p>{item.date}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
      </div>
  )
};
```

Is there a way to make my react-router automatically go to a new webpage like the  tag would?

Answer (score 0):

I my be misunderstanding this question, but if you just want your app to link to other sites just use the HTML anchor tag: `<a href="http://myawesomeworkproject.com">`.

You'll just need an identifier on workedItems to check whether to render an `<a>` tag or a `<Link>`